# Firestore Patch mapValue REST API

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to send a post request using POSTMAN to update the value for one map entry, but I am unable to find the right syntax for this. This is how i posted the data in my db:

```
{
    "fields" : {
        "8" : { 
            "mapValue" : { 
                "fields" : {
                     "f1" :  { "stringValue" : "A" },
                     "end" :  { "integerValue" : "9" },
                }
            }
        },
        "9" : { 
            "mapValue" : { 
                "fields" : {
                     "f1" :  { "stringValue" : "A" },
                     "end" :  { "integerValue" : "10" },
                }
            }
        },
    }
}
```

How can I modify the value f1 of key 8 to "B" ?

Answer (score 4):

For an update to certain values, you need to use **PATCH**.
Firestore Map Values are *objects*, accessible through **update masks** in a *query parameter*, and you also need to define a **JSON request body** for the resource you want to update.

So, for the endpoint, it would look like this:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/databases/{database_id}/documents/{document_path}?updateMask.fieldPaths=KEYVALUE.VALUE
```

As you can see, you need to use **dot notation**, as map values are *objects*.

The request body:

```
{
"fields": {
    "A8": {
      "mapValue": {
        "fields": {
          "f1": {
            "stringValue": "B"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One thing to note, is that your keys are only numbers. Firestore doesn't like that, so change them for **alphanumerical keys** (like "A8" instead of "8"). Once you change them, access to your values, such as `A8.f1` will be possible.

If you want to update for multiple keys, add them to your query parameters with ampersands, like so:

```
?updateMask.fieldPaths=A8.f1&updateMask.fieldPaths=A9.f1
```

And add the extra JSON in order to make that change inside the same request;

```
{
"fields": {
    "A8": {
      "mapValue": {
        "fields": {
          "f1": {
            "stringValue": "B"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "A9": {
      "mapValue": {
        "fields": {
          "f1": {
            "stringValue": "C"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PS: Remember to use your Bearer Token to make requests.

Here's some links for reference on map values:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/Value

Answer (score 0):

You can update a document partially by an HTTP PATCH request to Google Cloud Firestore's REST APIs.

In this case you need to provide the following information in the request:

1) **document.name** as [Path Parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch#path-parameters) : The resource name of the document, for example projects/{project_id}/databases/{database_id}/documents/{document_path}

2) **updateMask** as [Query Parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch#query-parameters): The fields to update.

3) **Request body** : [JSON representation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents#resource:-document) of how you want the document to look like, after the update operation.

**API Reference**: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch

This is similar to `set()` operation in the client libraries where you can pass a `SetOption` which can be set to `merge` to merge the updates to an existing document.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So how does one set merge:true using the HTTP PATCH of the REST API, to be able to change only a map value, without changing other key-values? Or does one have to present the entire map in the Request Body?