# Google firestore REST API

Tags: rest, google-cloud-firestore

I trying method "databases.documents.patch" for creating new document in firestore (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch)

```
const result = await firestore.projects.databases.documents.patch({
      name,
      auth,
      "fieldPaths": [
        {"messageUID": {
          "stringValue": messageUID
        }}
      ]
    })
```

But I got an error:

```
Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "fields[messageUID][stringValue]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'fields[messageUID][stringValue]' could not be found in request message.
    at Gaxios._request (/srv/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:85:23)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

If i remove line with `"stringValue": messageUID` EMPTY document will be created, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're conflating your query parameters with the request body. The patch request requires to specify both the fields you want to update and the new values thy will hold; the first are passed through query parameters and the second are passed in the request body. In the example you posted you're mixing them up.

As per the [patch documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch) the fields to update should be passed with [*DocumentMask*](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/DocumentMask) format and the values for them with [*Document*](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents#Document) format. You might take a look at this related threads [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702227/firestore-patch-mapvalue-rest-api), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937981/firestore-rest-api-query-parameters-type-of-object) and check how they differ from your example. Additionally, you could use the API explorer to create requests and check how they're shaped.

On the other hand, I will recommend not to use raw http rest requests to interact with Firestore since there are client libraries available for node.js that are more reliable and allow you not to care about shape details. In particular the [create](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#create) and [set](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#set) methods will accomplish the same task with a friendlier syntax. The following example is adapted from the [node.js reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/):

```
let documentRef = firestore.collection('collection').doc();

documentRef.create({MessageUID: MessageUID}).then((res) => {
  console.log(`Document created at ${res.updateTime}`);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(`Failed to create document: ${err}`);
});
```